# How to evaluate model's performance using a K-S test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am wondering if a K-S test or other test can be used for comparing models' performance. For example, I have two prediction models, the prediction result of first model is `[x1, x2, x3, ..., xn]`, the prediction result of the second model is `[z1, z2, z3, ..., zn]` . The ground truth of the prediction is `[y1, y2, y3, ..., yn]`.

The lengths of the lists are not the same, but roughly around 4,000.

The prediction target is kind of noisy, so I am not expecting the prediction results perfect. I conducted the `scipy.stats.kstest` from `scipy`, something like

```
stats.kstest(x, y)
```

and

```
stats.kstest(z, y)
```

The return for `x` is

```
statistics:0.14
p-value:1.5e-40
```

And the return for `z` is

```
statistics:0.12
p-value:1.5e-14
```

I am wondering how I should interpret the results for the models, like which statement is right?

(1) Although both models do not perfectly predict `y`, `z` model is still better than than `x` model because the statistical value is lower.

(2) Both `z` model and `x` model are really bad and they cannot be compared. Because both `p-values` are extremely small.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  What do you believe the test provides you?  For prediction problems, one would typically compare models on some loss function.  Any particular reason why you're not taking that approach?

Comment: The problem is a little bit of specific, what I predicted is the degree of nodes in a graph. It's kind of a tradition to compare the node degree distributions, rather than only a mean square error. It is OK to get a wrong node degree value for each node, as long as the final node degree distribution is similar.

Comment: If you're looking at the distribution, why not compare qq plots?  I just don't think a hypothesis test is really what you want here.

Comment: Another reason of using the hypothesis test is the `x`, `y`, and `z` are not the same length. The model also generates some 'nodes' that do not exist in ground truth. It's more like a 'generative' model, rather than an element-wise prediction model.

Comment: What values can these degrees of nodes take?

Comment: They are integer values, like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. But in my another application, it can also be continuous values (not node degrees any more).